# Is it possible to use the depthSort argument in breadthfirst layout in dash-cytoscape?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cytoscape, dash-cytoscape

I'm plotting a network using [Dash-Cytoscape](https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape), using the `breadthfirst` layout, as documented [here](https://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/breadthfirst).

I would like to control the order of appearance of elements on the same level. The JS API has the `depthSort` argument to achieve this, but I couldn't figure out how to pass a callback in Python that the frontend can live with.

Things I've tried:

1. `"depthSort": lambda a,b: a - b`
2. `"depthSort": "(a,b) => a - b"`
3. `"depthSort": "function (a,b) { return a - b}"`

### Minimal example:

I would like to get this:

```
   1
3     2
```

but what I'm getting is this:

```
   1
2     3
```

```py
from dash import Dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = cyto.Cytoscape(
    elements=[
        {"data": {"id": "1", "label": "1"}},
        {"data": {"id": "2", "label": "2"}},
        {"data": {"id": "3", "label": "3"}},
        {"data": {"source": "1", "target": "2"}},
        {"data": {"source": "1", "target": "3"}},
    ],
    layout={
        "name": "breadthfirst",
        "roots": ["1"],
        # "depthSort": ?
    },
)

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options that expect a JS function are not supported in Python, because it implies passing the function as a string, and thus it would require Cytoscape.js to `eval`uate arbitrary strings, which is probably something the maintainers don't want for security reasons.

That said, Dash supports [clientside callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks) (JS) so we can still assign the function within a callback :

```
from dash import Dash, Output, Input, State
import dash_cytoscape as cyto

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = cyto.Cytoscape(
    id="cyto",
    elements=[
        {"data": {"id": "1", "label": "1"}},
        {"data": {"id": "2", "label": "2"}},
        {"data": {"id": "3", "label": "3"}},
        {"data": {"source": "1", "target": "2"}},
        {"data": {"source": "1", "target": "3"}},
    ],
    layout={
        "name": "breadthfirst",
        "roots": ["1"]
    }
)

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function (id, layout) {
        layout.depthSort = (a, b) => b.data('id') - a.data('id');
        cy.layout(layout).run();
        return layout;
    }
    """,
    Output('cyto', 'layout'),  # update the (dash) cytoscape component's layout
    Input('cyto', 'id'),       # trigger the function when the Cytoscape component loads (1)
    State('cyto', 'layout'),   # grab the layout so we can update it in the function
    prevent_initial_call=False # ensure (1) (needed if True at the app level)
)

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

NB. We need to execute [`cy.layout(layout).run()`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#layout.run) because no element are added/removed so it won't run automatically.

Comment: It's so horrible and so beautiful. Thank you, works perfectly.

Comment: Update: this made my nodes and edges unmovable, I'm assuming due to the `run()` command. Do you know of a way to fix this?

Comment: It works fine for me, nodes are positioned correctly _and_ I can still move them. The run() command only applies the layout config to (re)position nodes, if you didn't set nodes to be locked in the config (cf. `autoungrabify`, `autolock`, `grabbable`) you should be able to move them, if this is not the case please provide a mwe.